# .htaccess keep same uri segment as referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site translated into several languages. The Chinese and Japanese versions have a structure like this: www.example.com/ja/page.html, where the "ja" uri segment represents in this case the Japanese version. The English version page is just www.example.com/page.html.

I want to write a RewriteCondition in my .htaccess file that will automatically add the "ja" (or "ch") uri segment in the right place when the user clicks on a link in the English version on the site. Unfortunately I find .htaccess rules to be impossibly hard.

So for example, when the user is on www.example.com/ch/about-us.html, and they click on a link whose URL is www.example.com/home.html, I want them to be redirected to www.example.com/ch/home.html.

Is this really that difficult? I haven't found any tutorials or questions on SO about it at all. I believe I need to make use of the HTTP_REFERER directive but that is about as far as I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:www\.)?example\.com/(ch|ja)/.+\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note: **This is untested.**

Comment: Thanks anyway but this doesn't work. It just adds www./ a whole bunch of times to the URL

Comment: Yeah like I said not tested. I did change it a little.

Comment: I made another change to the answer to fix www problem. See if this helps.

Comment: Still not working, I'm afraid. I went ahead and updated the links manually, so unless you're still curious, it's been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, ok I was using the tester and it appeared to work fine. http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Like using that tester, use those rules, the menu URL as the URL and the referer link in the 3rd field on that tester and it shows it should work.